# Edge - Unable to establish websocket connection to http://localhost

Tags: selenium-webdriver, websocket, automation, microsoft-edge, selenium-edgedriver

I am not able to test my automation at all on my edge browser. Getting this error:

```
Unable to establish websocket connection to http://localhost:
```

Tried updating the `EdgeDriver`, downloaded and ran the `edgedrive.exe` file (which was successful) but nothing worked.

Already tried adding this line once:

```
EdgeOptions options = new EdgeOptions();
options.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_INSECURE_CERTS, true);
options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
options.setCapability("ignore-certificate-errors", true);
              WebDriverManager.edgedriver().avoidResolutionCache().proxy(PROXY).setup();
driver.set(new EdgeDriver(options));
driver.get().manage().window().maximize();
driver.get().manage().deleteAllCookies();
```

And this the other time:

```
EdgeOptions edgeOptions = new EdgeOptions();
edgeOptions.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
```

No luck!! Please help :)

Comment: What is the version of Selenium? I tried these code in C#, but it has some errors, such as the definition of setCapability does not exist. Does it run in java environment?

Comment: I am on the 4.0.0 version of selenium api, selenium-java and selenium-edge-driver and using - OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Zulu 8.70.0.23-CA-win32) (build 1.8.0_372-b07) @XudongPeng